# Conflicting declaration while compiling 6.3.0 gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

Ubuntu Xenial, x86_64
Compiling 6.3.0 gcc

nativ gcc version is 5.4.0

Error Source:

```
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DGENERATOR_FILE -fno-PIE -I. -Ibuild -I../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc -I../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/build -I../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/../include  -I../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/../libcpp/include  \
-o build/genmddeps.o ../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/genmddeps.c
```

---

Error:

```
In file included from ./bconfig.h:3:0,
             from ../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/genmddeps.c:18:
./auto-host.h:2321:16: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 #define rlim_t long
            ^
In file included from ../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/genmddeps.c:19:0:
../../gcc-6.3.0/gcc/system.h:488:23: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘void* sbrk(int)’
 extern void *sbrk (int);
                   ^
```

I am trying to compile gcc from scratch. My config options are

```
../gcc-6.3.0/configure --target=arm-eabi --prefix=/local/development/arm-project/tools/ --enable-languages=c --with-newlib --without-headers
```

Can anyone please help with debugging?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I see same issue...

Comment: @mattismyname no, i did not and did not follow it anymore. I downloded the pre built binaries for arm and continued working. If you find the answer, please post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try (and edit accordingly):

```
tar xzf gcc-6.3.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-6.3.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-6.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++
make
make install
```

Source: [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC)

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue, by installing `gmp-devel`, `mpfr-devel` and `libmpc-devel`. See [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) for details.

There are some additional [requirements for GCC 9.1.0](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/gcc.html) such as DejaGnu 1.6.2 and GDB 8.3 (solved my libiberty make target error).

If you have more than one compiler installed, use the GCC compiler:

```
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
```